# How do I load the images and the csv file for object detection in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

[Data loader in Image Classification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DktS.png)

[Small Target Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wllTZ.jpg)

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmgob.png)

I am new to object detection and don't know how to use the dataloader for the task. In image clasification, I know that we can load data for image classification from image_dataset_from_directory in tensorflow and I am looking for similar function to load the images and annotation files in csv format.
I have a csv file that contains the bounding box co-ordinates in the form of (x0,y0,width,height) for every image. How do i load the csv annotation file along with the images for object detection?

Images names are 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg and so on. I have added a picture of how I load the images directly from the folder structure for image classification.

I am trying to use the TensorFlow library in python language.

Comment: [mre] is required. what language, what libraries?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I am trying to use the TensorFlow library in python language.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @NikeshDevkota, Please refer to this [documentation](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-convert-tensorflow-object-detection-csv-data-to-coco-json-format-d0693d5b2f75) to know about loading csv data to odject detection model. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your csv file to below code to create an annotation files.

```
def annotation(row):
    annotation = {}
    area = (row.xmax -row.xmin)*(row.ymax - row.ymin)
    annotation["segmentation"] = []
    annotation["iscrowd"] = 0
    annotation["area"] = area
    annotation["image_id"] = row.fileid

    annotation["bbox"] = [row.xmin, row.ymin, row.xmax -row.xmin,row.ymax-row.ymin ]

    annotation["category_id"] = row.categoryid
    annotation["id"] = row.annid
    return annotation
```

After creating annotations You will need to transform those to TFRecord. Then select the object detection model which you want to train. Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/40296dbbbe1d3ed72946d328e20f5a16) for complete code to create annotations and this [document](https://neptune.ai/blog/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api) for creating Tf records and training the model. Thank You.

Comment: I will try to follow the reference link and create TFrecords. Thank you